# Flatten a list in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, flatten, dcg, difference-lists

I've only been working with Prolog for a couple days.  I understand some things but this is really confusing me.

I'm suppose to write a function that takes a list and flattens it.

```
?- flatten([a,[b,c],[[d],[],[e]]],Xs).  
Xs = [a,b,c,d,e].                           % expected result
```

The function takes out the inner structures of the list.

This is what I have so far:

```
flatten2([],[]).
flatten2([Atom|ListTail],[Atom|RetList]) :-
      atom(Atom), flatten2(ListTail,RetList).
flatten2([List|ListTail],RetList) :-
      flatten2(List,RetList).
```

Now, this works when I call:

```
?- flatten2([a,[b,c],[[d],[],[e]]], R).
R = [a,b,c,d,e].                         % works as expected!
```

But when I call to see if a list that I input is already flattened, is returns `false` instead of `true`:

```
?- flatten2([a,[b,c],[[d],[],[e]]], [a,b,c,d,e]).
false.                                   % BAD result!
```

Why does it work on one hand, but not the other?  I feel like I'm missing something very simple.

Comment: With this specific task, please also consider a more general case: What should `?- flatten([X], Ls).` yield? You may think that it "obviously" should yield `Ls = [X]`. However, you then have the following problem: `?- flatten([X], Ls), Ls = [X], X = [a].` *succeeds*, **but** if we simply exchange the goals by commutativity of conjunction, we get: `?- Ls = [X], X = [a], flatten([X], Ls).`, or more compactly, `?- flatten([[a]], [[a]]).`, which of course *must fail* because `[[a]]` is not a flat list. So, which is it? Fail or succeed? This shows that this is really not a nice relation at all.

Comment: This is why I recommend you take a look at `append/2`. It limits this relation to a more meaningful and often also more practically useful version.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The definition of `flatten2/2` you've given is busted; it actually behaves like this:

```
?- flatten2([a, [b,c], [[d],[],[e]]], R).
R = [a, b, c] ;
false.
```

So, given the case where  you've already bound `R` to `[a,b,c,d,e]`, the failure isn't surprising.

Your definition is throwing away the tail of lists (`ListTail`) in the 3rd clause - this needs to be tidied up and connected back into the list to return via `RetList`. Here is a suggestion:

```
flatten2([], []) :- !.
flatten2([L|Ls], FlatL) :-
    !,
    flatten2(L, NewL),
    flatten2(Ls, NewLs),
    append(NewL, NewLs, FlatL).
flatten2(L, [L]).
```

This one recursively reduces all lists of lists into either single item lists `[x]`, or empty lists `[]` which it throws away. Then, it accumulates and appends them all into one list again out the output.

Note that, in most Prolog implementations, the empty list `[]` is an atom *and* a list, so the call to `atom([])` and `is_list([])` both evaluate to true; this won't help you throw away empty lists as opposed to character atoms.

Comment: You're right it was busted.  I don't know why I was getting the right answer before.

I understand how your approach works but how does it get rid of empty lists?

Also, why is `[]` an atom?

Comment: @ToastyMallows it gets rid of `[]`s because appending a list and an `[]` gets you your same list back. `[]` is both atom and list for historical reasons. Look up "cons" and "nil". `[]` is what's known in LISP as "nil".

Comment: (I am new to prolog) What does the ! stand for? I had the same solution, but without ! it does not work

Comment: `!` is a special character called a _cut_ in Prolog. It tells the interpreter to cut (ignore) other choices to prevent backtracking. For more information, [Learn Prolog Now!](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse43) has a nice tutorial.

Answer (score 11):

You can maintain your lists open-ended, with both a pointer to its start, and an *"ending hole ⁄ free pointer"* (i.e. logvar) at its end, which you can then instantiate when the end is reached:

```erlang
flatten2( [], Z, Z):- !.                                        % ---> X
flatten2( [Atom|ListTail], [Atom|X], Z) :-                      %      .
    \+is_list(Atom), !,                                         %      .
    flatten2( ListTail, X, Z).                                  %      Y
flatten2( [List|ListTail], X, Z) :-                             %      .
    flatten2( List,     X, Y),       % from X to Y, and then    %      .
    flatten2( ListTail, Y, Z).       % from Y to Z              %      Z --->
```

You then call it as

```erlang
flatten2( A, B):- flatten2( A, B, []).
```

That way there's no need to use `reverse` anywhere. This technique is known as "difference lists", but it's much easier just to think about it as "open-ended lists" instead.

---

*update:* This is much easier coded using the [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg) syntax. Since it is unidirectional (the first argument must be fully ground), why not use cuts after all:

```erlang
flattn([]) --> [], !.
flattn([A|T]) --> {\+is_list(A)}, [A], !, flattn(T).
flattn([A|T]) --> flattn(A), flattn(T).
```

Testing:

```erlang
16 ?- phrase(flattn([a,[b,c],[[d],[],[e]]]), [a, b, c, d, e]).
true.

17 ?- phrase(flattn([a,[b,c],[[d],[],[e]]]), R).
R = [a, b, c, d, e].

18 ?- phrase(flattn([a,[b,c],[[d],[],[e]]]), R, [1,2,3]).
R = [a, b, c, d, e, 1, 2, 3].

19 ?- phrase(flattn([a,[b,X],[[d],[],[e]]]), [a, b, c, d, e]).
X = c.
```

If the definition were fully declarative, the last one should've succeeded also with `X=[c] ; X=[[],c] ; ... ; X=[[c]] ; ...`; alas, it isn't.

(*edit2*: simplified both versions, thanks to @[mat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1613573/mat)'s comments!)

Comment: Technically I like your solution best, but it didn't work for me in SWI-Prolog 6.

Comment: I tried `flatten2([1,[8,3],[3,[5,6],2],8], X).` and it returned `false.`

Comment: @FK82 you're right, I should've used `atomic/1` instead of `atom/1`. -- fixed it, thanks!

Comment: `!//0` is a DCG nonterminal, there is no need to wrap it. For example, you can write `flattn([]) --> !.` However, you *must* use `phrase/2` to portably access a DCG! An implementation is free to choose any expansion method it wants, and indeed need not expand the DCG to explicit differences at all. For example, in some abstract machines, using a different argument order may be a lot more efficient. If you rely on a particular expansion method, it will be increasingly harder to implement such optimizations in future systems.

Comment: I have upvoted this because the DCG version is the first version of the predicate in this whole thread that I think I have a chance to understand ;-) You can still simplify it though!

Answer (score 2):

Prolog's list notation is *syntactic sugar* on top of very simple prolog terms. Prolog lists are denoted thus:

1. The empty list is represented by the atom `[]`. Why? Because that looks like the mathematical notation for an empty list. They could have used an atom like `nil` to denote the empty list but they didn't.
2. A non-empty list is represented by the term `.\2`, where the first (leftmost) argument is the *head* of the list and the second (rightmost) argument is the *tail* of the list, which is, recursively, itself a list.

Some examples:

- An empty list: `[]` is represented as the atom it is:

  ```
  []
  ```
- A list of one element, `[a]` is internally stored as

  ```
  .(a,[])
  ```
- A list of two elements `[a,b]` is internally stored as

  ```
  .(a,.(b,[]))
  ```
- A list of three elements, `[a,b,c]` is internally stored as

  ```
  .(a,.(b,.(c,[])))
  ```

Examination of the head of the list is likewise syntactic sugar over the same notation:

- `[X|Xs]` is identical to `.(X,Xs)`
- `[A,B|Xs]` is identical to `.(A,.(B,Xs))`
- `[A,B]` is (see above) identical to `.(A,.(B,[]))`

Myself, I'd write `flatten/2` like this:

```
%------------------------
% public : flatten a list
%------------------------
flatten( X , R ) :-
  flatten( X , [] , T ) ,
  reverse( T , R )
  .

%--------------------------------------------
% private : flatten a list into reverse order
%--------------------------------------------
flatten( [] , R , R ) .        % the empty list signals the end of recursion
flatten( [X|Xs] , T , R ) :-   % anything else is flattened by
  flatten_head( X , T , T1 ) , % - flattening the head, and
  flatten( Xs , T1 , R )       % - flattening the tail
  .                            %

%-------------------------------------
% private : flatten the head of a list
%-------------------------------------
flatten_head( X , T , [X|T] ) :- % if the head is a not a list
  \+ list(X) ,                   % - simply prepend it to the accumulator.
  ! .                            %
flatten_head( X , T , R     ) :- % if the head is a list
  flatten( X , T , R )           % - recurse down and flatten it.
  .

%-----------------------
% what's a list, anyway?
%-----------------------
list( X ) :- var(X) , ! , fail .
list( []    ) .
list( [_|_] ) .
```

Comment: I tried `flatten([a,[b,c],[],[[[d]]]],X)` call with your code and it didn't work. The atom-handling case seems missing in your version.

Comment: but now it produces `X = [a, [c, b], [[[d]]]]`.

Comment: what does list( X ) :- var(X) , ! , fail . mean?

Comment: `list(X) :-var(X) , ! , fail.` say, "If `X` is an unbound variable, X is *not* a list." The `!, fail.` bit eliminates the choice point (so it can't follow the predicate's other alternative paths) and fails. With that that guard clause, an unbound variable would unify with `[]` and succeed. And on backtracking, it would unify (again) with `[_|_]` and succeed a second time. A true/false check for list-ness should be deterministic.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an accumulator based version for completeness:

```
% flatten/2
flatten(List, Result) :- flatten(List, [], Result).

% auxiliary predicate flatten/3
flatten([], Result, Result).
flatten([Head| Tail], Part, Result) :- 
    is_list(Head),
    !, 
    flatten(Head, HR),
    append(Part, HR, PR),
    flatten(Tail, PR, Result).
flatten([Head| Tail], Part, Result) :- 
    append(Part, [Head], PR),
    flatten(Tail, PR, Result).
flatten(X, Part, Result) :-
    fail.
```

Comment: usually we try to avoid `append`, unless it's O(1), like with e.g. difference lists, `app(A-B,B-C,A-C).`.

Comment: @WillNess Yeah, well I'm new to Prolog. :-) I tried to avoid append but couldn't get it to work using lists only.

Comment: nicely done. :) (you didn't do the usual flatten, flatten, append - you tried to make at least one recursive call as a tail call; good). -- BTW, a clause that always `fail`s can be safely removed altogether - whether it matches a clause's head and immediately fails, or just fails because there was no (any more) matches, doesn't matter: a fail is a fail.

Answer (score 2):

Building on [`if_//3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29367581/4609915) and `list_truth/2`, we can implement `myflatten/2` as follows:

```
myflatten(Xs,Ys) :-
   phrase(myflatten_aux(Xs),Ys).

myflatten_aux([]) --> [].
myflatten_aux([T|Ts]) --> 
   if_(neither_nil_nor_cons_t(T), [T], myflatten_aux(T)),
   myflatten_aux(Ts).

:- use_module(library(dialect/sicstus/block)).

:- block neither_nil_nor_cons(-).
neither_nil_nor_cons(X) :-
   \+nil_or_cons(X).

nil_or_cons([]).
nil_or_cons([_|_]).

neither_nil_nor_cons_t(X,Truth) :-
   (  nonvar(X)
   -> (  neither_nil_nor_cons(X) -> Truth = true
      ;                             Truth = false
      )
   ;  nonvar(Truth) 
   -> (  Truth == true -> neither_nil_nor_cons(X)
      ;  Truth == false,  nil_or_cons(X)
      )
   ;  Truth = true,  neither_nil_nor_cons(X)
   ;  Truth = false, nil_or_cons(X)
   ).
```

Sample queries (taken from other answers, and comments to answers):

```
?- myflatten([[4],[[5,6],[7,[8],[9,[10,11]]]]], Xs).
Xs = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11].

?- myflatten([1,[8,3],[3,[5,6],2],8], Xs).
Xs = [1, 8, 3, 3, 5, 6, 2, 8].

?- myflatten([a,[b,c],[],[[[d]]]], Xs).
Xs = [a, b, c, d].

?- myflatten([a,[b,c],[[d],[],[e]]], Xs).
Xs = [a, b, c, d, e].
```

`neither_nil_nor_cons_t` and `not(nil_or_cons_t)` describe have same solutions, but the solution order differs. Consider:

```
?- myflatten([A,B,C],Xs), A=a,B=b,C=c.
A = a,
B = b,
C = c,
Xs = [a, b, c] ;                       % does not terminate universally
```

Answer (score 2):

Without any other predicate, with tail-recursion only.

```
flatten([[X|S]|T], F) :- flatten([X|[S|T]], F).
flatten([[]|S], F) :- flatten(S, F).
flatten([X|S], [X|T]) :- \+(X = []), \+(X = [_|_]), flatten(S, T).
flatten([], []).
```

Comment: `?- flatten(Ls0, Ls).` yields: **Out of local stack**.

Comment: Variables are not allowed in the first argument, indeed. Otherwise, I believe that the correct solution is computed if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a solution using `findall`, so I'll add it. (it will work if the list is fully ground, including that all its elements are fully ground)

First, we define how to test for a list:

```
list(X) :- var(X), !, fail.
list([]).
list([_|_]).
```

and the [transitive closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure) of `member`, we call it `member*`:

```
'member*'(X, Y) :- member(X, Y).
'member*'(X, Y) :- member(Z, Y), 'member*'(X, Z).
```

The flattened list is all the solution of `member*` which are not lists:

```
flatten(X, Y) :- findall(Z, ('member*'(Z, X), \+ list(Z)), Y).
```

Example:

```
?- flatten([[4],[[5,6],[7,[8],[9,[10,11]]]]],Y).
Y = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11].
```

Comment: This renames variables element-wise in, say, `[[f(X),g(X)]]`

Comment: nice idea! too bad it doesn't work for the above mentioned case, but it works for the fully ground lists, so, it's still nice. :)