# Why are binary trees implemented as nested terms, not nested lists?

Tags: prolog

I know it is a vague question, but still: what is it about terms that makes them more appropriate for nesting than lists? Or are lists (internally) a trivial case of nested terms?

(I realize I could "use the source", SWI-Prolog, for example, but a pointer in the right direction would be appreciated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a list makes sense if you do not know beforehand the number of elements. If it is clear that every entity has a fixed number of elements (as is the case with nodes in a binary trees), using terms with fixed arities is more memory efficient than lists. Consider for example the structure:

```
node(Name, Left, Right)
```

This takes 4 memory cells in total: one for the functor, and three for the arguments.

Using a list (in this case `[Name, Left, Right]`) takes roughly twice the memory in total:

```
'.'(Name, '.'(Left, '.'(Right, []))).
```

3 cells for list functors ('.'), 1 cell for `[]`, and three for the arguments.

Also a nitpick: As you of course know, a list is also a term. Terms that are not lists, numbers, pairs etc. are sometimes called "structures".

Comment: Alright, this clears it up indeed. Admittedly, I had missed the fact that lists are a special form of terms. I somehow imagined list representation can be implementation-dependent, but it's dictated by the language specification instead.

Answer (score 0):

As noted, Prolog lists are just syntactic sugar on top of two terms: '.'/2 and '[]'. See this answer for details: [Flatten a list in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059572/flatten-a-list-in-prolog/9069057#9069057)