# Trying to break elements which are lists in a list?

Tags: prolog, logic, dcg

I am trying to write a program which make the following:

```
?- g([2,3, [22,[3],9] ,4,[5],99],X).

X= [2,3,22,[3],9 ,4,5,99]
```

So it searches for lists in the given list and replace it by their elements without brackets [].

So I wrote this program:

The first block just searches for the first element in the list which is list
If there is no such element it returns `[there_is_no_list]`.

```
first_list_in_the_list([],[there_is_no_list]):-!.  
first_list_in_the_list([H|_],X):-is_list(H),X=H,!.  
first_list_in_the_list([_|T],X):-first_list_in_the_list(T,X).
```

The first block works in prolog perfectly.

The second block just search in the list for an element X and then split the  list into a two lists one is the list of all elements before X and the second   is the elements after X.

```
splite_when_find_element([H|T],H,[],T):-!.  
splite_when_find_element([H|T],X,F,G):-
    splite_when_find_element(T,X,F1,G),append([H],F1,F).
```

it also works fine in Prolog.

and the third block is append, and it joins two list together in a new list.

```
append([],L,L).  
append([H|T],L,[H|U1]):- append(T,L,U1).
```

and the last part is:

```
gg(L,L):-first_list_in_the_list(L,[there_is_no_list]),!.    
gg(L,U):-first_list_in_the_list(L,X),
         splite_when_find_element(L,X,F,G),gg(G,R),append(F,X,E),
         append(E,R,U).
```

When I give a `query [2,[3],5]` I get also `[2,[3],5]` and I really don't understand why it does this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flatten a list in Prolog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059572/flatten-a-list-in-prolog)

Comment: Your example doesn't get rid of all the sublists but seems to remove only one level in between. For example, `[1, 2, [3, [4], 5], 6]` becomes `[1, 2, 3, [4], 5, 6]` if I try to follow your example. Is that what you intend?

Comment: yes, exactly. that is what i want, just one level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple recursive solution will also work. Recursion is done by the head of the input list. In the non-trivial case, when the head is a list itself, we just append the rest of the flattened list to it. In the code below, it has not flattened `Rest` yet in `append(H, Rest, Out)`, but it will be, after the recursive call of `g(In, Rest)`. Cut after the append call ensures that backtracking won't consider the last case, where the head will appear in the output as-is.

```
% Base case, empty list.

g([], []).

% First recursive case: head is list.
% Append remaining elements to it.

g([H|In], Out):-
    append(H, Rest, Out), !,
    g(In, Rest).

% Second recursive case: head is not list.
% Will appear as-is in the output.

g([H|In], [H|Out]):-
    g(In, Out).
```

Answer (score 1):

also a DCG can do

```
lev, X --> [X], {is_list(X)}, lev.
lev, [X] --> [X], lev.
lev --> [].
```

test:

```
?- phrase(lev,[a,[b,c,[d]],e],L).
L = [a, b, c, [d], e] .
```

Answer (score 0):

To flatten 1 level of a nested list, try something like this:

```
flatten1( Xs , Ys ) :-        % to flatten a list
  flatten1( Xs , [] , Ys ) ,  % - invoke the worker predicate
  .                           %

flatten1( [] , T , R ) :-          % if we get to to the empty list
  reverse(T,R)                     % - just reverse the accumulator and we're done.
  .                                %
flatten1( [X|Xs] , T , R ) :-      % if the head of the list is unbound 
  var(X) ,                         % - check for being a var 
  ! ,                              % - cut (to eliminate problems on backtracking
  T1 = [X|T] ,                     % - prepend the head of the list to the accumulator
  flatten( Xs , T1 , R )           % - and recurse down
  .                                %
flatten1( [[]|Xs] , T , R ) :-     % if head of the list is an empty list, skip it
  flatten1( Xs , T , R )           % - ignore it and recurse down
  .                                %
flatten1( [[X|Ns]|Xs] , T , R ) :- % if head of the list is a non-empty list
  X1 = [Ns|Xs] ,                   % - prepend the tail of the sublist to the list
  T1 = [X|T] ,                     % - prepend the head of the sublist to the accumulator
  flatten( X1 , T1 , R )           % - and recurse down
  .                                %
flatten( [X|Xs] , T , R ) :-       % if the head of the list is something else (except an unbound variable)
  T1 = [X|T] ,                     % - prepend the list head to the accumulator and
  flatten( Xs , T1 , R )           % - recurse down
  .                                %
```