# Add a character before each atom in a list in prolog

Tags: prolog

I am trying to learn Prolog.I am suppose to write a predicate which will place 'bubbles' before each atom in a list.The empty list is unchanged.

```
?-addbubbles([a,b,8,c],X).

X=[bubbles,a,bubbles,b,8,bubbles,c]
```

I wrote the foll Code:

```
Addbubbles([],[]).

addbubbles([H|T],[A|B]) :-append([bubbles],[H],A),addbubbles(T,B).
```

But the output is not as expected :

```
?- addbubbles([a,v,2,4,f],M).

M = [[bubbles,a], [bubbles,v], [bubbles,2], [bubbles,4], [bubbles,f]] ;
```

How can i remove the extra brackets so that i get the output as:

```
M = [bubbles,a, bubbles,v,bubbles,2,bubbles,4,bubbles,f];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use [`append/3`](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse24) here. Just write down the specification verbatim:

```
% The empty list is left alone:
addbubbles([], []).

% Add 'bubbles' before each element in the list (recursively):
addbubbles([Element|OldTail], [bubbles,Element|NewTail]) :-
    addbubbles(OldTail, NewTail).
```

A list has the form `[Element1, Element2, Element3… | Tail]`. So you can use `[bubbles,Element|NewTail]` to prepend two elements.

And it works:

```
?- addbubbles([a,b,8,c],X).
X = [bubbles, a, bubbles, b, bubbles, 8, bubbles, c].

?- addbubbles(X, [bubbles, a, bubbles, b, bubbles, 8, bubbles, c]).
X = [a, b, 8, c].
```

If you want to use `append/3`, then you need to flatten the list. C.f. "[Flatten a list in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059572/flatten-a-list-in-prolog)".

But look out for typos in your code. In Prolog you finish clauses with a dot, and the capitalization is important.