# Prolog how do I append a list of lists into one list?

Tags: list, prolog, append

So I'm totally new to Prolog and need some help. I'm trying to take a list of lists like `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8]]` and create a list like `[2,3,5,6,8]`, so basically all the values into a new list besides the first of each list. I got this:

```
test5(X,[[_|X]|_]).
test5(X,[_|A]) :- test5(X,A).
```

which returns `[2,3]` and then `[5,6]` and then `[8]` each time I press enter. I'm not sure how to make them run all at once and make them into a list. I tried using append in different ways but I could not get this working. Any idea on how to implement this? Thanks!

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059572/flatten-a-list-in-prolog

Answer (score 3):

You have the common predicate `flatten/2`, which almost does the job:

```
?- flatten([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8]], L).
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8].
```

There are [many implementations of `flatten/2` available](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/home/swipl/lib/swipl/library/lists.pl?show=src#flatten/2), just google it.

If you know that the list of lists is not nested, you should rather use [`append/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/home/swipl/lib/swipl/library/lists.pl?show=src#append/2).

Then, you need to drop the first element of each list before appending:

```
list_tail([_|T], T).
```

Then:

```
?- maplist(list_tail, [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8]], T), append(T, L).
T = [[2, 3], [5, 6], [8]],
L = [2, 3, 5, 6, 8].
```

It might be a good exercise to take a more careful look at the implementation of `append/2` linked above. With a small change in the definition (literally removing 1 character and adding 5) it will do the dropping and appending in the same step, without traversing the original list twice.

**EDIT**

So why is it that [@repeat's initial solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30094318/1812457) does not terminate when the first argument is not a proper list, but the second is a proper list?

```
nt_tails_append([[_|T]|Ls], As) :-
    append(T, Ws, As),
    nt_tails_append(Ls, Ws).
```

It is because when the first argument to `nt_tails_append/2` is a free variable, the first two arguments to `append/3` above are variables, too. When we call `append/3` in this mode, we get, by definition:

```
?- append(A, B, L).
A = [],
B = L .
```

In other words, the second and the third arguments are now unified. With the definition of `nt_tail_append/2`, this means that the recursive call gets the same second argument as the original call, and a new free variable as the first argument. This is an endless loop, of course.

(Tellingly, if you care to look at the definition of `append/2` linked above, you will see that the first argument `must_be` a `list`.)

How does this help?

```
tails_append(Ls, As) :-
    maplist(list_tail, Ls, T),
    append(T, As).

list_tail([_|T], T).
```

The way that `maplist` is defined, all list arguments will be instantiated to proper lists. So you can safely use `append/3` (here, used in the definition of `append/2`).

Comment: +1 for mentioning `append/2`. It encourages a more declarative view than `flatten/2` and is moreover what is usually actually needed in practice. Instead of `drop_first/2`, I suggest `list_rest/2` to make clear that it is a true relation which can be used in all directions.

Comment: @mat or maybe `list_tail/2`?

Comment: Everything is better than *imperative* wording, which always suggests a direction, whereas you have implemented something much more general.

Comment: @repeat Yes, but you don't explicitly say what is different between the two solutions. See my edit for details.

Comment: @repeat and anyway, I would also rather say `must_be(list, X)` for the first argument than use the `maplist`+`append/2` solution that I originally suggested: although you do get answers, I am not convinced of their usefulness. My original answer, on the other hand, was meant to provoke some reading and thinking. Especially when a production quality modern Prolog implementation as SWI-Prolog is free software, it is a sin not to look at the code.

Comment: @repeat yes, the concrete order of the clauses of `append/3` leads to the first solution being what it is.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you could do it using `append/3`:

```
lists_concatenatedTails([],[]).
lists_concatenatedTails([[_|Xs0]|Xss],Ys) :-
    append(Xs0,Ys0,Ys),
    lists_concatenatedTails(Xss,Ys0).
```

Sample query:

```
?- lists_concatenatedTails([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8]], Xs).
Xs = [2, 3, 5, 6, 8].
```

---

#### Edit 2015-05-07

Note that the code that @Boris suggested (using `list_tail/2`,`maplist/3`,`append/2`) also gives answers for the following query:

```
?- maplist(list_tail,Xss,Yss), append(Yss,[1,2,3]).
Xss = [[_G97, 1, 2, 3]],                   Yss = [[1, 2, 3]]         ;
Xss = [[_G97], [_G106, 1, 2, 3]],          Yss = [[], [1, 2, 3]]     ;
Xss = [[_G97, 1], [_G106, 2, 3]],          Yss = [[1], [2, 3]]       ;
Xss = [[_G97, 1, 2], [_G106, 3]],          Yss = [[1, 2], [3]]       ;
Xss = [[_G97, 1, 2, 3], [_G106]],          Yss = [[1, 2, 3], []]     ;
Xss = [[_G97], [_G106], [_G115, 1, 2, 3]], Yss = [[], [], [1, 2, 3]] ...
```

This doesn't terminate universally---nor do we expect it to: the set of solutions is infinite in size and it can, in this case, only be covered by an infinite sequence of answers.

In the following equivalent query `lists_concatenatedTails/2` "loops" right away:

```
?- lists_concatenatedTails(Lss,[1,2,3]).
% not a single answer within finite time
```

Only when constraining the length of `Lss` right away, fair enumeration can be achieved:

```
?- length(Lss,_), lists_concatenatedTails(Lss,[1,2,3]).
Lss = [[_G23, 1, 2, 3]] ;
Lss = [[_G26], [_G29, 1, 2, 3]] ;
Lss = [[_G26, 1], [_G32, 2, 3]] ;
Lss = [[_G26, 1, 2], [_G35, 3]] ;
Lss = [[_G26, 1, 2, 3], [_G38]] ;
Lss = [[_G29], [_G32], [_G35, 1, 2, 3]] ...
```

Comment: Unification in the body usually urges me to find reasons why it has been delayed. There is either a cut before it, or it is used in as the condition in a `Condition -> Action`...

Comment: You are truly committed to Prolog-uing, then.

Comment: Thank you guys, I really appreciate the help. I was afraid I would get no answers :)

Comment: Nit: It is not the infinity (of the set) of solutions that causes non-termination — think of length(Xs,1) which *has to* terminate — but the infinity of *answers* that are able to represent that infinite set of solutions that cause non-termination

Comment: You left out the crucial point: it's about the number of answers necessary to represent that infinite set of solutions. Not just answers.