# Transform embedded lists to one list

Tags: list, prolog

using append/2 we can aggregate a list of lists to one list

```
append([[a], [b], [c]], L) .
L= [a, b, c].
```

at this point, the question that arises is; how to do it with a list as follows :

```
L=[[[[a]]],[[[[c]]]],[[c]]]
```

Comment: see [flatten](http://www.swi-prolog.org/search?for=flatten%2F2)/2

Comment: You can use `flatten/2` as @CapelliC points out, but where is the list coming from? If you have a predicate which is accumulating such a list and finding you need to flatten when you're done, that's an indicator that your predicate may be in need of refactoring to avoid the embedded lists.

Comment: The common `flatten/2` has a bunch of inherent anomalies. Avoid it, unless you produce a safe, logical definition.

Comment: @false flatten/2 not available in sisctus

Comment: @lurker , yes  rightly, it is a list that accumulates in order to parse an expression

Comment: I find a solution in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059572/flatten-a-list-in-prolog)

Comment: @AnsPiter: There is a [good solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30824413/772868) by repeat, but it is quite complex. The others are incorrect.

Comment: @false what about the answer of sharky!

Comment: `X=[a], flatten2(X,[a]).` succeeds as one might expect, but `flatten2(X,[a]), X=[a].` fails. Even `flatten2(X,[a])` alone fails.

Comment: `flatten2([],[[]]).` succeeds. `[[]]` is certainly not a flattened list.