# Flattening lists in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, flatten

How can I flatten a list in Prolog, for example:

```
    from A = [["a","b"],["c"]]
    to B = ["a", "b", "c"] ?
```

Comment: This too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059572/flatten-a-list-in-prolog

Comment: The only clean way to do it is to use `flatten/2`. For example, in SWI-Prolog: `?- flatten([[a,b],[c,[d]]], R).
R = [a, b, c, d].
`

Comment: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/lists.pl?show=src#flatten/2

Answer (score -2):

A list can be flattened using maplist and append, in the following way.

A two-level list may be flattened as shown.

```
    ?- A=[["a","b"],["c"]],maplist(append,[A],[B]).
    A = [["a", "b"], ["c"]],
    B = ["a", "b", "c"].
```

A three-level may be flattened with two passes of the command.

```
    ?- A=[[["a","b"]],[["c"]]],maplist(append,[A],[B]),maplist(append,[B],[C]).
    A = [[["a", "b"]], [["c"]]],
    B = [["a", "b"], ["c"]],
    C = ["a", "b", "c"].
```

Mixtures of two and three levels in a list results in an error from two passes of the command.

```
    ?- A=[[["a","b"]],[["c"]],["d"]],maplist(append,[A],[B]),maplist(append,[B],[C]).
    false.
```

Mixtures of two and three levels in a list can only be partially flattened with one pass of the command.

```
    ?- A=[[["a","b"]],[["c"]],["d"]],maplist(append,[A],[B]).
    A = [[["a", "b"]], [["c"]], ["d"]],
    B = [["a", "b"], ["c"], "d"].
```

Comment: That is not flattening **a** list, but flattening a very specific list.

Comment: It is a terrible answer but since you have answered it yourself I am wondering if you really _want_ any help at all. You seem to _need_ help but this is a different topic.

Comment: You can also use the custom predicate foldr to partially flatten lists, as follows: foldr(Function,A,L,B):- reverse(A,C),foldl(Function,C,L,B),!. and foldr(append,A,[],B).