# Is it possible to define an append function for a list of predicates?

Tags: prolog, append

How do I define an append function for a list of predicates?

Ex. of a list:

```
listMember( 10,
  listMember( 8,
    listMember( 0,
      listMember( 9,
        empty_member
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Ex. of append call for instance:

```
append( 10, listMember(8, listMember(0, listMember(9, empty_member))), List )
```

edit: it just needs to handle appending one term

Answer (score 3):

Prolog's list notation (`[ a, b , ... ]`) is just simple syntactic sugar on top of ordinary prolog terms. The empty list is denoted by the atom `[]`; a non-empty list is denoted by the term `./2`, where the first argument in the term is the *head* of the list, and the second the *tail* of the list, being either the empty list or a non-empty list (`.(a,.(b,[]))` being the actual representation of `[a,b]`).

See my answer [here for a full explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059572/flatten-a-list-in-prolog/9069057#9069057).

This is the canonical implementation of `append/3`:

```
append( []    , L , L     ) .
append( [H|T] , L , [H|R] ) :- append(T,L,R) .
```

Eliminating the syntactic sugar gives you this:

```
append( []     , L , L      ) .
append( .(H,T) , L , .(H,R) ) :- append(T,L,R) .
```

That should get you on your way.

**Edited to add:**

If you you just want to append a single item to a list, it's a simple matter of traversing the list. When you reach the end, you insert it. Something like (using normal list notation):

```
append_item( X , []     , [X]    ) .
append_item( X , [Y|Ys] , [Y|Zs] ) :- append_item(X,Ys,Zs).
```

or, *sans* syntactic sugar,

```
append_item( X , []      , .(X,[]) ) .
append_item( X , .(Y,Ys) , .(Y,Zs) ) :- append_item(X,Ys,Zs).
```

**Edited to note:** As noted by @keldan-chapman in the comments, as of SWI Prolog v7+, lists are no longer `./2` for a non-empty list, and the atom `[]` for the empty list. As of SWI Prolog v7+, a non-empty list is denoted by `'[|]'/2` and the empty list by "*a special constant which is printed as* `[]`".

Go figure.

For details, see the SWI Prolog documentation at [§ 5.1, Lists Are Special](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=ext-lists).

Comment: It may be worth noting, that in SWI-prolog it seems that `./2` is [depreciated](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=f((%27.%27)/2)) and that non empty lists are denoted by `'[|]'/2` instead.

Comment: @KeldanChapman — That's weird. Answer amended to note that little . . . deviance.

Comment: You mean "deprecated" @Keldan.