# How to convert a list of list to a list of tuples in prolog?

Tags: prolog

ex `[[a,b],[b,c]]` to `[(a,b),(b,c)]`.

```
% Define a predicate that takes a list of lists and returns a list of tuples
convert_list_to_tuple(ListOfLists, ListOfTuples) :-
    % Base case: if the input list is empty, return an empty list
    ListOfLists = [],
    ListOfTuples = [].

convert_list_to_tuple(ListOfLists, ListOfTuples) :-

    [Head|Tail] = ListOfLists,
    Head =.. Tuple,
    convert_list_to_tuple(Tail, TailTuples),
    ListOfTuples = [Tuple|TailTuples].
```

How to convert a list of list to a list of tuples in prolog?
Ex [[a,b],[c.d]]---> [(a,b),(c,d)]

Comment: These are not tuples. Not tuples.

Answer (score 1):

Can just use [maplist](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/3):

```
conv([A,B], (A,B)).
```

```
?- maplist(conv, [[a,b],[b,c]], L).
L = [(a, b), (b, c)].
```

Such tuples ("comma lists") are [a bad (i.e. confusing) choice](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/surprising-result-with-equals-dot-dot/4989/8). Better to use named atoms:

```
conv_term(Lst, Term) :-
    Term =.. [v|Lst].
```

```
?- maplist(conv_term, [[a,b],[c,d,e]], L).
L = [v(a, b), v(c, d, e)].
```

Answer (score 1):

Why would you use something like `(a,b)`? It works fine for arity 2, but add more elements — `(a,b,c,d,e)` — and it gets ugly:

```
','( a , ','( b , ','( c , ','( d , e ) ) ) )
```

[Prolog's lists are simple syntactic sugar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9069057/467473) on top of the term `./2`, with the atom `[]` representing the empty list. Hence, the list `[a,b]` is actually the term `.(a,.(b,[]))`. Congratulations! — you've just reinvented Prolog's list in a clumsy way.

Use a term instead.

Turning a list into such a tuple is trivial — just prepend the list with the desired *functor* (name) you want to use for the tuple and use the in-built `=../2` to map between the list and the tuple:

```
list_tuple( L , T ) :- T =.. [ tuple | L ] .
```

Once you have that, turning a list of lists into a list of tuples is likewise trivial:

```
lists_tuples( []     , []     ) .
lists_tuples( [L|Ls] , [T|Ts] ) :- list_tuple(L,T), lists_tuples(Ls,Ts) .
```

Evaluating

```
?- lists_tuples( [ [] , [a] , [a,b] , [a,b,c] , [a,b,c,d], [a,b,c,d,e] ] , Ts ) .
```

Yields the expected

```
Ts = [
  tuple,
  tuple(a),
  tuple(a,b),
  tuple(a,b,c),
  tuple(a,b,c,d),
  tuple(a,b,c,d,e)
]
```

And evaluating

```
?- lists_tuples( L, [tuple,tuple(a),tuple(a,b),tuple(a,b,c),tuple(a,b,c,d),tuple(a,b,c,d,e)] ).
```

Similarly yields the expected

```
L = [[], [a], [a,b], [a,b,c], [a,b,c,d], [a,b,c,d,e]]
```

You can fiddle with it at https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/JDhVptgN.pl